# Creating Team, Applying Security Label and Adding to Auto-labeling Policy, Unattended. Is this even possible?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, azure-authentication

I have a working PowerShell script that does all of this, with interactive login.  It's based off of the these main commands:

- Connect-MgGraph
- New-MgGroup (Creates group with appropriate sensitivity label.)
- New-MgTeam (Adds team to group.)
- Connect-IPPSSession
- Set-AutoSensitivityLabelPolicy (Adds team's SharePoint site to existing auto labeling policy.)

I need this to run unattended by Service Now after a request is approved.

In order to connect to MS Graph and execute this as a user account with stored credentials, I followed [this](https://doitpsway.com/how-to-connect-to-the-microsoft-graph-api-using-saved-user-credentials) guide. The script was able to create the group and apply the label, but the **New-MgTeam** command errors out with:

*Missing scope permissions on the request. API requires one of 'Team.Create, Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All'. Scopes on the request 'AuditLog.Read.All, Dir
ectory.AccessAsUser.All, email, openid, profile'*

The problem is, I'm not connecting as an app through an app registration, it's a user with the appropriate roles (teams admin and compliance admin).  I assume this has something to do with the use of a token as spelled out in the guide I linked.

Originally, I attempted to use an app registration with the appropriate roles, but the **New-MgGroup** command failed with the error "App-only token is not supported".

Answer (score 0):

When I ran same code as you to create team, I got  **same error**  like below:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-MgGraphViaCred -credential $cred

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Teams

$params = @{
    "template@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"
    displayName = "My Sample Team"
    description = "My Sample Team’s Description"
}

New-MgTeam -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, I registered one Azure AD application and granted  **API permissions**  like below:

[image]

You can make use of below script by generating  **access token**  for application using client credentials and used it to create team like below:

```
$tenantID = "2773f7fd-d343-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" #your tenantID or tenant root domain
$appID = "f72491ac-f9ae-4b10-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe" #the GUID of your app.
$client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" #client secret for the app

#Prepare token request
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + $tenantId + '/oauth2/v2.0/token'

$body = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_id = $appID
    client_secret = $client_secret
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}

$tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $url -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop 

$AccessToken = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $AccessToken

$params = @{
    "template@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"
    displayName = "Imran Team"
    description = "Imran Team’s Description"
    members = @(
        @{
            "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember"
            roles = @(
                "owner"
            )
            "user@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('7488bc42-6a7c-4ba2-xxxxxxxxxxx')"
        }
    )
}

New-MgTeam -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, team created successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I was unable to get this to run unattended: Set-AutoSensitivityLabelPolicy (Adds team's SharePoint site to existing auto labeling policy).  Currently working on stepping through it in the GUI using Power Automate Desktop.